# binding an Expression<Func> selector to a linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I am using a library that converts linq expressions into event queries. (streaminsight).

I need solve this problem:

Given some values, and an expression that combines values.

```
var a = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
var b = new[] { "x", "y", "z" };
Expression<Func<string, string, string>> combine = (x, y) => x + ":" + y;
```

I need to bind the combine function to the following query whilst still maintaining the expression syntax.

```
var query =
    from f in a
    from g in b
    select combine(f, g);

query.Dump();
```

Unfortunately the target application for this linq statement does not support `Func<string, string, string>` in it's raw format because the query is interpreted at runtime.

I get this error: **Additional information: The following expression is not supported by Microsoft Complex Event Processing LINQ provider: 'Invoke(value(System.Func`3...**

I think I will solve the problem if I can reproduce the expression as it would have been with:

```
var query =
    from f in a
    from g in b
    select x + ":" + y;
```

I want to pass the select part of the query into a function as an `Expression<Func<...` argument.

I tried this, which obviously doesn't quite work:

```
var query =
    a.SelectMany(a1 => b, (x, y) => new { x, y })
     .Select(_ => combine(_.x, _.y));
```

I have simplified this question, but for reference, the real query looks like this:

```
        var ms =
            requestStream
                .AlterEventLifetime(
                    _ => _.StartTime - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000),
                    _ => _.EndTime + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000) - _.StartTime)
                .SelectMany(requestData => responseStream
                    .AlterEventLifetime(
                        _ => _.StartTime - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000),
                        _ => _.EndTime + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000) - _.StartTime),
                    (requestData, responseData) => new {requestData, responseData})
                .Where(@t => @t.requestData.CorrelationTicketId == @t.responseData.CorrelationTicketId)
                .Where(@t => @t.requestData.CorrelationTicketId > 0
                             && @t.requestData.SuccessFailureCode != 3001)
                .Select(@t => expression(@t.requestData, @t.responseData));
```

Comment: Does `.SelectMany(a1 => b, combine)` work?

Comment: No, CS1929 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'SelectMany' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.SelectMany<string, string, string>(IQueryable<string>, Expression<Func<string, int, IEnumerable<string>>>, Expression<Func<string, string, string>>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<string>'

Comment: besides that, I really need to figure out how to bind it to the select, as my real world scenario has many where clauses too.

Comment: The first error is caused by using arrays as mock sources; it goes away if you call `AsQueryable` on `a`. I think you might get some joy out of calling `.Select(expression)` rather than `.Select(t => expression(...))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to compile the expression before you can use it as function:

```
var a = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
var b = new[] { "x", "y", "z" };

Expression<Func<string, string, string>> combine = (x, y) => x + ":" + y;
var fu = combine.Compile();
var query =
        from f in a
        from g in b
        select fu(f, g);
```

Comment: Any reason for down?

Comment: your're right, that's all it took. works a charm... I thought that would result in the same error as Func<string, string, string> but it doesnt'

Comment: Ahh the life of expressions, so powerfull and so much to learn about it, good answer though +1 from my side

Answer (score 0):

HimBromBeere's answer will work, and if you are only ever going to be using it with in-memory `IEnumerable<string>` sources for `a` and `b` then it's the one to go for.

Otherwise, while it will still work with `IQueryable<string>` it will do so by passing pulling the relevant strings into memory, rather than pushing the expression down to the provider so that it can become an SQL query, etc.

To deal with `IQueryable<string>` **as** `IQueryable<string>` you would want:

```
var query = a.AsQueryable().SelectMany(_ => b, combine);
```

(When run on `IEnumerable<string>` this becomes a slightly more expensive way of doing `a.SelectMany(_ => b, combine.Compile());` which is another way of writing the answer HimBromBeere gave).

Answer (score -1):

Additional explanation:

An `Expression<Func<T>>` is an uncompiled expression tree. You need to use it if you're going to be sending it to a provider that needs to parse expression trees and convert them(rather than just run the code), such as Entity Framework.

Your case involves a provider that does require this so, rather than compiling the expression before use(which wouldn't work when you try to reuse that code block with an actual StreamInsight source) you're better off simply calling `AsQueryable()` on the mocked arrays, like so:

```
// using function form of LINQ because it's more flexible
// also, using the join because that's what your query does - a cartesian product
var query = a.AsQueryable().Join(b.AsQueryable(), x => 0, x => 0, combine);
```

I'd also suggest you do a bit of research into how the IQStreamable interface provider and extension methods (from StreamInsight) actually work because I don't think that bare arrays are the best choice for mocking event streams.

Comment: You can't invoke an expression like `combine(f, g)`.

Comment: The compile was definitely what was required. Func<... does not work with the stream insight provider. Expression<Func<... With compile works perfectly.

Comment: @JonHanna My mistake. I use the query form of LINQ so rarely I forgot that you can't give it expressions. Edited + explanations.